# tenserflow tutorial error or mistake

Tags: tensorflow

Incorrect code from training examples
https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

```
    sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    adder_node = a + b  # + provides a shortcut for tf.add(a, b)

    print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: 13, b:4.5}))
    print(sess.run(adder_node, {a: [1,3], b: [2, 4]}))
```

0.0
[ 0.  0.]

What is the problem?

Comment: This looks like it may be a bug. Please post a description of your configuration on the [TensorFlow GitHub issues page], and somebody will look into it.

Comment: That works fine for me. Did you do anything else before the part you posted?

Comment: (I can confirm that it works fine for me as well, with TensorFlow 1.0 on CPU.)

Comment: I had this same issue. I resolved it by updating my NVIDIA driver and restarting.